# String function clause matching

Tags: erlang

I'm running into a problem when writing some simple erlang code for an old Advent of Code task.

The following program is supposed to read lines, group characters in a string by occurrence and then count the number of lines that have a repeat of three characters.

```
count_occurrences([], Map) -> Map;
count_occurrences([H | T], Map) ->
    count_occurrences(T, maps:put(H, maps:get(H, Map, 0) + 1, Map)).

count(Line, Count) ->
    Map = count_occurrences(Line, #{}),
    case lists:member(3, maps:values(Map)) of
        true -> Count + 1;
        false -> Count
    end.

run() ->
    {ok, Binary} = file:read_file("data.txt"),
    Lines = binary:split(Binary, <<"\n">>, [global]),
    Result = lists:foldl(fun count/2, 0, Lines),
    Result.
```

However, I get this error message:

```
10> c(day2).   
{ok,day2}
11> day2:run().
** exception error: no function clause matching day2:count_occurrences(<<"bpacnmelhhzpygfsjoxtvkwuor">>,#{}) (day2.erl, line 5)
     in function  day2:count/2 (day2.erl, line 10)
     in call from lists:foldl/3 (lists.erl, line 1263)
```

I don't understand why `<<"bpacnmelhhzpygfsjoxtvkwuor">>,#{}` doesn't match the second "count_occurrences" function clause - a string is the same as a list, right? Why doesn't it match [H | T]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go([_H|_T], _X) ->
    "First arg was a list";
go("a", _X) ->
    "First arg was a string";
go(<<"a">>, _X) -> 
    "First arg was a binary".
```

In the shell:

```
5> a:go(<<"a">>, #{a=>1, b=>2}).
"First arg was a binary"
```

and:

```
6> a:go("a", #{a=>1, b=>2}).    
"First arg was a list"
```

> a string is the same as a list, right?

Yes, a double quoted string is a shortcut for creating a list of integers where the integers in the list are the ascii codes of the characters. Hence, the second function clause above will never match:

> a.erl:6: Warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause
> at line 4 always matches

But....a binary, such as `<<"abc">>` is NOT a string, and therefore a binary is not a shortcut for creating a list of integers.

```
8> "a" =:= [97].
true
```

Okay, you knew that.  But, now:

```
9> "a" =:= <<"a">>.
false

10> <<"a">> =:= <<97>>.
true

11> "a" =:= <<97>>.
false
```

And, finally:

```
13> <<"abc">> =:= <<97, 98, 99>>.
true
```

The last example shows that specifying a double quoted string inside a binary is just a shortcut for specifying a comma separated list of integers inside a binary--however specifying a double quoted string inside a binary does not somehow convert the binary to a list.

Comment: Thank you, the real confusion turned out to be the difference between a string and a binary. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also iterate through a binary with only slightly different syntax:

```
count_occurrences(<<>>, Map) -> Map;
count_occurrences(<<H, T/binary>>, Map) ->
    count_occurrences(T, maps:put(H, maps:get(H, Map, 0) + 1, Map)).
```

By default, `H` is assumed to be a byte, but you can add modifiers to specify how many bits you want to select, and more. See the [documentation for the Bit Syntax](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#bit-syntax-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

You get this error cuz function `count_occurrences/2` expect first argument `list` - `[<<"bpacnmelhhzpygfsjoxtvkwuor">>]` or `"bpacnmelhhzpygfsjoxtvkwuor"`  but was put `binary` - `<<"bpacnmelhhzpygfsjoxtvkwuor">>`. Double check input data `Line` in function `count/2` of module `day2.erl` at line 10:

```erlang
1> is_list([]).
true
2> is_list("").
true
3> is_list(<<"">>).
false
4> is_list(binary_to_list(<<"">>)).
true
```